# Monte Carlo simulation faster with Numba on a PC but not on another

Tags: python, performance, numpy, simulation, numba

I'm working on an algorithm (for some sort of PCA) and I test its performance according to a metric. It is evaluated by Monte Carlo i.e. averaging over several samples for a choice of parameter.
Initiality, my code consists of simple loops for parameters and samples with Numpy functions for the algorithm.

I heard about the package Numba to speeed up my code. I found out that I get a 5x improvement in speed only rewriting the Numpy part to fit Numba standarts and adding the `@njit` decorator.
However, I tested the same improved version on another PC (both are laptops with Intel i7's)  and found out that I get no speed improvement on this second PC.

I am dumbfounded about why this could be the case.

edit:

More details about the two PCs.

PC 1:

- Python 3.7.6
- Numba 0.48.0
- Intel Core i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz (4 cores)
- RAM 8 Go

PC 2:

- Python 3.7.4
- Numba 0.49.0
- Intel Core i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz (6 cores)
- RAM 16,0 Go

And here is a minimal reproducible example.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

@jit(nopython=True)
def multivariate_normal(m,C):
    L = np.linalg.cholesky(C)
    X = np.random.randn(m.shape[0])
    return(L @ X + m)


@jit(nopython=True)
def gendata(p, d, k, n, sig_s):

    H = np.random.randn(d,k)
    u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(H, full_matrices=False)
    H = u @ vh
    rest = np.zeros((p-d, k))
    U0 = np.concatenate((H,rest),axis=0)

    X = np.empty((p,n))
    for i in range(n):
        b = multivariate_normal(np.zeros(p),np.identity(p))
        s = multivariate_normal(np.zeros(k),(sig_s**2) * np.identity(k)) 
        x = U0 @ s + b
        X[:,i] = x

    return((X,U0))

@jit(nopython=True)
def geomspace(a,b,n):
    seq = np.linspace(np.log(a),np.log(b),n)
    return(np.exp(seq))


@jit(nopython=True)
def Afe(U,U0):
    '''
    Average Fraction of Energy of subspace U based on original subspace U0.
    '''
    Oorth,r = np.linalg.qr(U)
    afe = np.trace(Oorth.T @ U0 @ U0.T @ Oorth) / np.trace(U0 @ U0.T) 
    return(afe)
    
@jit(nopython=True)
def sim2a():
    p = 50
    d = int(0.99 * p)
    k = 5
    sig_s = np.sqrt(10)

    
    ns = geomspace(3*k,3*p,10).astype(np.int32)
    echs = 50
    
    mc_afe_pca = np.empty(ns.shape[0])
    mc_afe_sphpca = np.empty(ns.shape[0])
    
    for n in range(ns.shape[0]):
        res_pca = np.empty(echs)
        res_sphpca = np.empty(echs)
    
    
        for e in range(echs):
            
            #print(n,e)
            X,U0 = gendata(p,d,k,ns[n],sig_s)
            sX = np.diag(X.T @ X)
            
            #PCA
            u, sig, vh = np.linalg.svd(X.T, full_matrices=False)
            Upca = vh.T[:,:k]
            res_pca[e]= Afe(Upca,U0)
            
            #Spherical PCA
            Xn = X / np.sqrt(sX)
            u, sig, vh = np.linalg.svd(Xn.T, full_matrices=False)
            Usph = vh.T[:,:k]
            res_sphpca[e] = Afe(Usph,U0)
            
        mc_afe_pca[n] = np.mean(res_pca)
        mc_afe_sphpca[n] = np.mean(res_sphpca)
        
    return((mc_afe_pca,mc_afe_sphpca))

#first run for compilation before measurements
mc_afe_pca,mc_afe_sphpca = sim2a()

#Graph 
p = 50
k = 5
ns = geomspace(3*k,3*p,10).astype(np.int32)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
plt.plot(ns,mc_afe_pca,'+-',label="PCA")
plt.plot(ns,mc_afe_sphpca,'x-',label="Spherical PCA")
plt.xlabel("n")
plt.ylabel("AFE")   
plt.legend()
plt.plot()

#Measure
def sim2atimer():
    start = time.time()  
    a,b= sim2a()
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
    
sim2atimer()

#Now, replace @jit by #@jit and reexecute the code to compare.
# The option Parallel=True was erased from @jit()
```

**In fact, while working on this example, I had the idea to erase the `Parallel=True` option in the `@jit` decorator, which prompted a warning that it was not used, and that fixed the discrepancy problem.**

Now, I still don't know why only one PC was affected.

Comment: Did you compile it ahead of time? The first run to compile in Numba is slower. After that it is faster if you use same input type to your functions.

Comment: I highly doubt that this question can be answered without additional information like: the numba version on the 2 PC, the python version, the code, the specifications of the machines (at least the processor and the memory). What about providing a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where the speed-up change regarding the machine?

Comment: @Ehsan yes I precompiled it

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you for the response. I am adding an edit for completion